# fitBounds Doesn't Work; setCenter Does

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When I'm adding a marker via coordinates, I'm having no problems using fitBounds(), but when I'm using geocoding of an address, fitBounds() focuses the map on the ocean.

However, if I use the same coordinates with setCenter(), it works. The problem is that this would only work for one point.

Here's my code:

```
function createMarkerFromAddress(address, labelOptions, infoWindowOptions) {
    //Create Label Options
    labelOptions = $.extend({}, labelOptionDefaults, labelOptions);

    //Create Info Window Options
    infoWindowOptions = $.extend({}, infoWindowDefaults, infoWindowOptions);

    //Create Geocoder
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //Geocode Address & Add to Map
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                draggable: false,
                map: map,
                icon: markerIcon,
                labelContent: labelOptions.content,
                labelAnchor: labelOptions.anchor,
                labelClass: labelOptions.className,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            //Add click event for InfoWindow
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker) {
                return function () {
                    //Load proper information for clicked campus
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowOptions.content);

                    //Open Info Window
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker));

            //Extend bounds
            bounds.extend(
                new google.maps.LatLng(
                    results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    results[0].geometry.location.lng())
            );

            map.setCenter(
                new google.maps.LatLng(
                    results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    results[0].geometry.location.lng()));
        } else {
            console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
```

This is almost identical to my createMarkerFromCoordinates method, except it has the geocode() call to get coordinates from the specified address.

Comment: Oh... Here's the way I'm calling fitBounds(): 
        if (options.fitAllMarkers === true) {
            //Fit bounds to map
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

Comment: [If I use the posted code and fix all the missing variables, it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2xrfy1hp/1/).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code and it does work. The difference is that you're calling fitBounds() right after you add the one location. I've been trying to call it after it adds them all. I suppose it doesn't matter, but for reference, here is pretty much everything: https://jsfiddle.net/ericrovtar/9y1w5n45/

Comment: Oh! I think I know what's going on. Since the geocoding is happening asynchronously, my script keeps moving, even though the data hasn't returned yet. Therefore, there are no bounds to set. Does that make sense?

Comment: geocoding is asynchronous.  That is the way to do it.  You didn't provide a example that demonstrated your issue.

Comment: The jsfiddle I linked above shows the problem and why it was the asynchronous call triggering my issue and not yours. Is there a way to test when the call is complete?

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work.

Comment: If you know the number of locations (you didn't post that code), you can only run the fitBounds when the last one is geolocated, the issue will be handling the case where some fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the geocoder is asynchronous, you need to call `map.fitBounds` everytime you update the bounds.

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var labelOptionDefaults;
var infoWindowDefaults;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  createMarkerFromAddress("New York, NY", {}, {});
  createMarkerFromAddress("Newark, NJ", {}, {});
  createMarkerFromAddress("Baltimore, MD", {}, {});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


function createMarkerFromAddress(address, labelOptions, infoWindowOptions) {
  //Create Label Options
  labelOptions = $.extend({}, labelOptionDefaults, labelOptions);

  //Create Info Window Options
  infoWindowOptions = $.extend({}, infoWindowDefaults, infoWindowOptions);

  //Create Geocoder
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  //Geocode Address & Add to Map
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        draggable: false,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });

      //Add click event for InfoWindow
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
        return function() {
          //Load proper information for clicked campus
          infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowOptions.content);

          //Open Info Window
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker));

      //Extend bounds
      bounds.extend(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
          results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
          results[0].geometry.location.lng())
      );
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    } else {
      console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! I appreciate the help.